# map array of parts to string via regex in deno (typescript)

Tags: javascript, regex, deno

I used a regex `"(.*?)"` to get all the things between quotation marks in a string. After running the operations on the array provided by `exec()`, I now have an array of these slices to put back into the string. How might I map this array back to the string using the regex?

I know about replacing them all with one specific value, but I'm not sure how to do it with an array. Perhaps there's some kind of `map()` that takes a function that I can use to  `pop()` values from the array?

I'm quite new to Deno and JS in general (coming from a more low-level background), so sorry if I just missed a doc or something.

Comment: Can you add an example of input/output you expect?

Comment: When you do a regexp replacement, the replacement can be a function instead of a string. The function can return dynamically determined results, so it can do an array lookup.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande in my case, I'm trying to parse HTML and map all of the domains included to a different domain. I could probably circumvent this entire issue with a different design pattern.

essentially, there could be something like this:
`<a href="https://example.com/foo">foo</a>`
and i want to turn it into this:
`<a href="https://example.org/?url=https://example.com/foo">foo</a>`

Comment: @Barmar ok, that should probably work. which replace function are you referring to specifically? (not the one to input, i mean the regex method)

Comment: `result = str.replace(/regex/, (match, group1) => ...)`

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `exec()` for that. Just use `str.replace(/regexp/g, 'replacement string that uses $1 and $2')` to substitute capture groups into the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacement function is the easiest way to accomplish what you want.

```js
const html = `
    <a href="https://example.com/foo">foo</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="https://example.net/foo">foo</a>
`;

const result = html.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (match, group) => {
    return `"https://example.org/?url=${group}"`;
});

console.log(result);
```

You can also use a replace string with `$n` replacement pattern

```js
 const html = `
        <a href="https://example.com/foo">foo</a>
        <div></div>
        <a href="https://example.net/bar">bar</a>
 `;
 
const result = html.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, `"https://example.org/?url=$1"`);

console.log(result);
```